# jquery variable do not answer on time

Tags: jquery

hi i am working on a project its a voting script. 
as you think in this script i am trying to user not to vote more than 1 in 24 hours .
i have a php part it works great i record users ip and vote time .
on php part i also return total votes number after increase .
and in jquery part i wanna put that number into a small box .
i created a javascript variable and also make it integer

```
myApp={};
```

and i put jquery return value on it like this

```
myApp.vote=parseInt(result);
```

for example if site total votes is 10 when user clicks vote result alerts 11 after post complete (everthing is on the way) and then i put that number to myApp.vote i also want to put that number in a span like this

```
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#bar-3").find(".bar-percent").eq(0).html(myApp.vote);
```

here problem starts jquery puts in that span old vote number (10) but it must be 11

```
$(document).on("click", ".up", function(){
var vote;
var siteId=$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".g6").attr("siteid");
if(myApp.siteId!=siteId){



$.post("vote.php", {
    siteId: siteId,
    vote:"up"
}, function (result) {
    alert(result);
    myApp={};
    myApp.vote=parseInt(result);


    });
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#bar-3").find(".bar-percent").eq(0).html(myApp.vote);
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#bar-3").find(".bar-percent").eq(0).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#FFFF00",

    }, 200, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });



$(this).parent().parent().parent().children("#bar-3").find(".bar-percent").eq(0).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",

    }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });


}else if(myApp.siteId==siteId){
$(this).parent().append("<span>already voted  </span>").children("span").addClass("alreadyVoted").animate({
opacity: 0,


}, 2000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});;

};



myApp.siteId=siteId;
```

when i  try to put them into between html call then i can not select it because $(this )is not referencing anything this is my html part i wanna select 1311 but i couldnot do it

```
<div class="home_img_box p10 mt10">
<div class="g6" siteid="144">
<img class="syn_img" src="../sI/s/youtube_com-13-04-22.jpg">
</div>
<div class="g5">
<h3 class="handle">
youtube
<img id="up" class="up" src="./images/up.png">
<img class="down" src="./images/down.png">
</h3>
<p>youtube</p>
</div>
<img class="hit" src="./images/hit.png" alt="Hit">
<img class="vote" src="./images/vote.png" alt="Hit">
<div id="bar-1" class="jbar jbarPr jqbar horizontal" pr="9">
<span class="bar-label">PR</span>
<span class="bar-level-wrapper">
<span class="bar-level" data-value="9" style="height: 10px; width: 27px; background-color: rgb(214, 71, 71);"></span>
</span>
<span class="bar-percent">9</span>
</div>
<div id="bar-2" class="jbar jbarHit jqbar horizontal" hit="1254">
<span class="bar-label"></span>
<span class="bar-level-wrapper">
<span class="bar-level" data-value="1254" style="height: 10px; width: 0px; background-color: rgb(58, 137, 201);"></span>
</span>
<span class="bar-percent">1254</span>
</div>
<div id="bar-3" class="jbar jbarVote jqbar horizontal" vote="1311">
<span class="bar-label"></span>
<span class="bar-level-wrapper">
<span class="bar-level" data-value="1311" style="height: 10px; width: 0px; background-color: rgb(58, 137, 201);"></span>
</span>
<span class="bar-percent">1311</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `html` call within the callback you passed to `$.post`. As is, you're starting the request and then doing the animations without ever waiting for the request to complete.

Comment: but this time i can not select them because $(this) is not referencing anyhing

Comment: @synan54: Save `$(this)` in a variable outside of the callback and use that variable inside the callback.